# how to change rotating direction using onclick

Tags: javascript, webgl

I should make a star rotating on first run, once the mouse is clicked the star should change its color and rotate in the opposite direction, if clicked again it should change the color and the direction again and so on.

I made 2 matrices one for each direction

```
     function rotateZ(m, angle) {  // angle (distance) = velocity * time
      
        var csine = Math.cos(angle);
        var sine = Math.sin(angle);
      //  var sineanticlockwise= math.sin(angle)*-1;


        var mv0 = m[0], mv4 = m[4], mv8 = m[8];

        m[0] = csine *m[0]-sine *m[1];
       m[4] = csine *m[4]-sine *m[5];

       m[1] = csine *m[1]+sine *mv0;
       m[5] = csine *m[5] +sine *mv4;
     }

     function rotateclockwise(m, angle) {  // angle (distance) = velocity * time
      
        var csine = Math.cos(angle);
        var sine = Math.sin(angle)*-1;
      //  var sineanticlockwise= math.sin(angle)*-1;


        var mv0 = m[0], mv4 = m[4], mv8 = m[8];

        m[0] = csine *m[0]-sine *m[1];
       m[4] = csine *m[4]-sine *m[5];

       m[1] = csine *m[1]+sine *mv0;
       m[5] = csine *m[5] +sine *mv4;
     }
```

this is the animate function with a condition inside so that when the mouse event call it it changes direction every time the mouse is clicked but it doesn't work I tried putting it in the mouse event and still

```
     var click=true;
     var time_old = 0;
     var animate = function(time) {
        var dt = time-time_old;
        
        if (click=true)
        {
            rotateZ(mov_matrix,dt*0.002); // distance = time* velocity(speed)
        time_old = time;
        click=false;
        }

        else
        {
     rotateclockwise(mov_matrix,dt*0.002); // distance = time* velocity(speed)
        time_old = time;
        click=true;
        }
 
     /* Step5: Drawing the required object (triangle) */
     gl.clearColor(0.19, 0.19, 0.20, 1); // Clear the canvas
     gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST); // Enable the depth test
     gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear the color buffer bit
     gl.viewport(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); // Set the view port
     gl.uniformMatrix4fv(Mmatrix, false, mov_matrix);
     gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 9);  // Draw the triangles

        window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);   
     }


      function mouseFunction(e){

    var clickXrelativToCanvas = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft;
    var clickYrelativToCanvas = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop;


    color = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1];
    var colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "u_color");
    gl.uniform4fv(colorLocation, color);
      var time_old = 0;
     rotateZ(mov_matrix, dt*0.002);
     //rotateclockwise (mov_matrix, dt*0.002);

  };
     animate(0);
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to dig into (indentation, maths, etc), however, you definitely have an error in your `if` statement: `if (click=true)` - a single equal sign assigns a value. If you want to compare values, use double equal `==` or triple `===`. For starters, try fixing that.

Comment: You need to post more code **in the question itself**. From the help: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest** code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**." Maybe use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: yes thank you i didn't notice this i changed it but still the problem's the same

Comment: Is your question about angle math or about mouse interaction? Which part is going wrong? If you just need the rotation problem solved you could look into CSS `transform.rotate()`. It would save you a lot of code!

Answer (score 1):

There are issues with the code. Whether fixing them is enough to make your code work is not clear

First off the `if` is not checking if `click` is true, it's setting `click` to true.

```
if (click = true)    // bad
if (click === true)  // good
```

and in general you should [use `===` not `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

second the 2 code paths for the if both set `click`

```
  if (click === true) {   // <------------ fixed
    rotateZ(mov_matrix, dt * 0.002); // distance = time* velocity(speed)
    time_old = time;
    click = false;        // <------------ WHAT?
  } else {
    rotateclockwise(mov_matrix, dt * 0.002); // distance = time* velocity(speed)
    time_old = time;
    click = true;         // <------------ WHAT?
  }
```

It seems like you should delete those 2 lines otherwise every time through the loop it will just toggle click true -> false -> true -> false. Instead toggle click in the mouse function

```
function mouseFunction(e) {
  click = !click;
  ...
```

Not sure why this code is in the mouse function

```
     var time_old = 0;
     rotateZ(mov_matrix, dt*0.002);
```

A more common way to do this though would be to set a rotation speed

```
var rotationSpeed = 0.002;
var time_old = 0;
var animate = function(time) {
  var dt = time - time_old;
  time_old = time;

  rotateZ(mov_matrix, dt * rotationSpeed); // distance = time* velocity(speed)

  /* Step5: Drawing the required object (triangle) */
  gl.clearColor(0.19, 0.19, 0.20, 1); // Clear the canvas
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST); // Enable the depth test
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear the color buffer bit
  gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Set the view port
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(Mmatrix, false, mov_matrix);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 9); // Draw the triangles

  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}


function mouseFunction(e) {
  rotationSpeed = -rotationSpeed; // flip the direction of rotation

  var clickXrelativToCanvas = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft;
  var clickYrelativToCanvas = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop;


  color = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1];
  var colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "u_color");
  gl.uniform4fv(colorLocation, color);
};
animate(0);
```

It's also not common to set uniforms in mouse events. It only works because you're drawing 1 thing. As soon as you try to draw 2 things in different colors you'll need to move setting the color inside `animate` so in the mouse function you'd choose a color but on `animate` you'd call `gl.uinform4fv(colorLocation, color)`